# Word that means "to make sore?"

Tags: single-word-requests

Example sentence:

> She tried to lift herself from the bed but only managed to __ her biceps, as if she’d done arm wrestling. Still, she gave it another shot.

I thought of the word *strain* but I think it implies that there's an injury?

Comment: To my ear, 'strain' works fine. I think technically a strain _is_ a minor injury - that's why it hurts - but you've scaled it by equating it to arm-wrestling.

Comment: "Irritate" might work.

Comment: "Inflame" might also work, but "strain" is probably appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"She only managed **to hurt** her biceps."

HURT -- Definition in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hurt?utm_campaign=sd&utm_medium=serp&utm_source=jsonld)

> (transitive verb)  1 a :  **to inflict with physical pain :  wound**
>
> Examples:
>
> He hurt his back while moving some boxes.
>
> was seriously hurt in a car accident
>
> You're hurting my arm!

Answer (score 1):

> **Injure**
> [in-jer]
> verb (used with object)
>
> 1. to do or cause harm of any kind to; damage; hurt; impair: